# Passing data between fragments with value not reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass MyData(Parcelable object including ArrayList) from AFragment to BFragment.

Certainly,it works.However,the problem is that when I pass data(MyData) from AFragment to BFragment, the reference of arraylist(mList) is the same. This causes when I change value of mList in BFragment, Value of mList in AFragment changes as well.
I have no idea to resolve the problem.

I've looked at various articles about Parcelable,and finally I found out that Parcelable recreate instance only when two objects is in different task.

How can I pass data with a new instance?

I wrote codes like below.

**MyData**:

```
public class MyData implements Parcelable {

public List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>(0);

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeStringList(mList);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyData>() {
    public MyData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyData(in);
    }

    public MyData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyData[size];
    }
};

private MyData(Parcel in) {
    in.writeStringList(mList);
}

public MyData() {
}
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SampleFragment sampleFragment = new SampleFragment();
    replaceFragment(sampleFragment);
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (manager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName()) != null) {
        return;
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container_layout, fragment, fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

**AFragment**:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

MainActivity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mActivity = (MainActivity) context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample1, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.button) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(0);
        list.add("sample1");
        list.add("sample2");
        list.add("sample3");
        HogeData data = new HogeData();
        data.mList = list;
        SampleFragment2 sampleFragment2 = new SampleFragment2();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(sampleFragment2.getClass().getCanonicalName(), data);
        sampleFragment2.setArguments(bundle);
        mActivity.replaceFragment(sampleFragment2);
    }
}
}
```

**BFragment**:

```
public class SampleFragment2 extends Fragment {

MainActivity mActivity;
HogeData mData;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mActivity = (MainActivity) context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    mData = bundle.getParcelable(getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample2, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Make a copy of the data. Pass the copy.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any API in Android to deal with this problem except coping and passing the data?

Comment: No, because it has nothing to do with Android. You *happen* to be writing an Android app, which *happens* to try to pass some complex data from one fragment to another. You would run into the same problem in an ordinary Java program, when trying to pass some complex data from one object to another. You may wish to reconsider your data model and how you are creating a UI for it, to find ways to avoid passing the data between two fragments in the first place.

Comment: i understand.thank you